# How to insert a symbol like θ, α, Γ, Δ or anything in the MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any needs to change the table structure or which function, so please put the solution here. thanks in advance.

My example is as:

```
$find_regex = 'Δ';
$replace_regex = '&#916;';
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO regex_table (find_regex, replace_regex, import_date) VALUES ('$find_regex', '$replace_regex')");
```

When I run the above code, it executed successfully but instead of symbol(find_regex) it insert '?'

One more thing I have already tried all the suggestion likes htmlentities, htmlspecialchar and so on provided in others questions in stackoverflow but didn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_real_escape_string($data); //where $data is your string which contains special char 
refer [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Before saving to db you can encrypt your data by using htmlentities(), and while retrieving data from database you can decrpt by html_entity_decode() , See the following example may be it will help you:

```
    <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db  = 'test_001';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$find_regex = htmlentities('Δ');
$replace_regex = htmlentities('&#916;');
 $sql = "INSERT INTO regex_table (find_regex, replace_regex ) VALUES ("."'". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $find_regex)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $replace_regex)."')";
//exit;

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //For retrieving from database 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `regex_table`";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['find_regex'].'<br>'.$row['replace_regex'].'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }




        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: Or just drop using mysql_ functions, because they are deprecated, and use PDO with prepared statements & utf-8 everything.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Thanks to reply but I think you haven't tried yet it. I already tried this function as well as utf-8 but nothing resolved so it will be useful to post your code.